# How to avoid to work with "ConvertTo-Json" for use with powershell 2.0?

Tags: json, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I wrote a small script which also uses the command `ConvertTo-Json` in powershell 3.0
All in all it just monitors the usage of memory cpu and disk size, I put the script on my server and wanted to run it. But it didn't work because on the server is only PS2.0 installed and I can't get 3.0 there.

So how to avoid using `ConvertTo-Json` to make it work in powershell 2.0?

I grab data and in the end I use it like this :

```
$dataArray = ConvertTo-Json $array

Send-DataArray $dataArray
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.NET has a JSON reader and writer that is easy to use from PowerShell v2.  I [wrote up a blog post on how to use these types](http://rkeithhill.wordpress.com/2009/12/06/json-serializationdeserialization-in-powershell/).  There is also the DataContractSerializer in .NET that uses JSON IIRC.